# Can we stop calling each other by religious view?

Tags: discussion

I don't think it's appropriate to refer to each other as Atheist, Christian, Secular Humanist, Creationist, etc.

The site is about Christianity, and question about this religion are acceptable (and should have exactly the same answers), no matter what the author believes.

Also for answers--they should be clear for anyone to understand, and not specifically tailored.

So, please, let's avoid characterising posts by belief of the author.

--

To be more clear: specifying the denomination in the question or answer is OK if applicable to the content. This is specifically related to the persons writing the posts.

Answer (score 16):

If this was [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) and somebody posted a question about a common command line utility but didn't specify what platform they were working on, the first comment would be "What platform" because the GNU tools used in Linux is different than the BSD tools used in OSX, Solaris, OpenBSD and others. *The point of view of the OP is highly relevant to provide a good answer.*

Likewise an OP may ask for a solution that applies to a different platform. An OpenBSD guy might come along as say they are confused about how to use `find` on Ubuntu because the arguments are in a different order. *Here, the requested POV is critical.*

Lastly there are answers that are portable. These take the form of "This bit will go for any Unix, but for this bit you need X if on Linux and Y if on BSD and Z if in Solaris". These are also quite common. *Here, stating the scope of each bit of the answer is critical.*

This site is no different! **Christianity is far more diverse and has far more distinct traditions than even the behemoth of fragmentation in the computer world.** Without monikers for some of these, we will forever be chasing our tails.

As a Protestant, if somebody answers a question with "Catholics believe x and put it into practice using y" I can celebrate that, agree that it is a good answer and upvote it if it clear *even if I don't believe that is the 'true path'* or whatever you want to call it. I can respect their tradition and ask questions about them. I have asked questions specifically about Catholicism here and will continue to do so because there are several knowledgeable folks in the field.

**TL;DR**: Trying to deny folks the ability to use these monikers to identify the scope of their questions an answers is futile in the same way that StackOverflow would be useless without tags to separate C++ from PHP from RUBY from Fortran.

Answer (score 11):

In most fields of study understanding perspective is important. Sometimes there is more than one correct answer to a particular question. For example, in psychology anxiety disorders are approached and treated differently depending on the perspective of the psychologist. A behaviorist might use introspection and conditioning to treat anxiety, while a neuroscientist would probably use medication. Both are used, both can be successful, and both have disadvantages. You can't really claim to understand anxiety disorders unless you look objectively at the various perspectives.

The same is true in engineering, programming, medicine, philosophy, law, art, and the sciences. Christian denominations can have RADICALLY different perspectives and these differences are important. If you lumped my beliefs in with someone who believes in neglecting their dying child medical care I would be very displeased. Some Christians believe in evolution, some in free will, and some in a very literal interpretation of the Bible.

Logically you can't really claim to understand something unless you examine other perspectives, and rule them out as incorrect, or just not for you.

If you are suggesting there is only one Christian perspective, well that is just not true. I think if you were to describe your particular denomination and say it unequivocally applies to all of Christendom you would be subject to some criticism.

Answer (score 2):

For the most part I agree with you, which is why I'm not big on denominations. Most questions don't need any reference to religious view because a Christian truth is a Christian truth regardless. However, I don't think this can be a generalized rule for the fact someone's religious view can make a huge difference in how a question is answered. I am not Catholic so I won't accept an answer to a question I ask that answers by referencing the Catechism (no offense to Catholics, it just isn't part of my belief set). However, if a Catholic asks a question, using the Catechism is acceptable.

I think those classifications should be avoided if not necessary, but it cannot be made into a rule